# Вывод ошибок через allert посредством coffeeScript и Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, coffeescript

Необходимо вывести ошибки в alert(), дело лишь в том,что ошибки приходят в виде array. Аналогично я выводил ошибки, но лишь тогда когда она приходила как строка. Разобраться пока не могу, хелп

пример кода, когда работал со строкой

```
->

  $(".actions_sing_in").click (e) ->

  $("form#new_user").bind "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log data
    if data.success
      $('#sign_in').modal('hide')
      $('#sign_in_button').hide()
      $('#submit_comment').slideToggle(1000, "easeOutBack" )
    else
      alert 'Status: ' + status + ' Message: ' + data.data.message
```

Comment: А как это должно выглядеть? Просто через запятую все ошибки перечислить?

Comment: Зависит от такого, в какой форме у вас ответный JSON.